# Are "ئ" and "أ" two distinct letters?

Tags: arabic

In following two ayahs, are "[الْمَشْئَمَةِ](http://tanzil.net/#56:9)" and "[الْمَشْأَمَةِ](http://tanzil.net/#90:19)" two distinct words? If not, why their spelling are not the same?

```
وَ أَصْحابُ الْمَشْئَمَةِ ما أَصْحابُ الْمَشْئَمَةِ (56:9)
وَ الَّذينَ كَفَرُوا بِآياتِنا هُمْ أَصْحابُ الْمَشْأَمَةِ (90:19)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are the same word, and are not spelled differently.

You are using Tanzil.net: The issue is that in the first aya, you seem to have chosen the text format of "Uthmani" (under the "quran" toolbox), while in the second aya you have chosen the text format to be "simple". If you choose the same text format in both ayat, you will see that the words are just the same.

To understand the difference between the Uthamni and Simple formats, checkout [this link](http://tanzil.net/wiki/Quran_Text_Types).

Answer (score 0):

This question affects only the spelling of the Qur’an, not the reading, which in both cases is ʼaṣḥābu l-mašʼamati. In modern Arabic orthography you write this as أَصْحابُ الْمَشْأَمَةِ , but in the older orthography you do not write either the second alif in the first word, or the second alif in the second word, so you get أَصۡحَـٰبُ ٱلۡمَشۡـَٔمَةِ .The long vowel in the first word and the hamza in the second are not indicated in the rasm, but only by diacritics.

PS. In the last word the fatha should be above the hamza, not below it. For some reason this does not show properly with the SE font. I hope you understand what I am trying to convey. والله اعلم

Comment: I'm not sure this answers the question. The two examples in OP clearly have the hamza written above an alif and a dotless yaa respectively; your second example (and your post in general) is arguing for cases where the hamza is written above nothing at all.

Comment: All three spellings: ٱلۡمَشۡـَٔمَةِ , ٱلۡمَشۡـئَمَةِ , الْمَشْأَمَةِ are found in different masahif. The last mentioned is the oldest. My point is simply that these are spelling variants for exactly the same reading. They are not "distinct words". Does that not answer the question?

Comment: @goldPseudo nope it's a good attempt to explain, but the easiest way to answer is the one of Tamer. Even if i would disagree because the original rasm wouldn't include any hamza!